# What's the name of this curvy looking brick, 2x3 with an overhang

Tags: part-identification, slope

What's the name of the brick shown below?

[image: Brick]

I've searched many sites including BrickLink and Lego itself but to no avail. Help?

**EDIT**
I think I found the name of this brick: 47456 Slope Brick Round 3 x 2 x 2/3 with Flap and Two Studs, Modified Wing End 2 x 3 x 2/3. Is this correct though?

Answer (score 4):

[Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=48082#T=C) refers to it as 'LegoBrick, Modified 2 x 3 x 2/3 Two Studs, Wing End'.

Lego Shop at Home refers to it as 'Plate w. Bows 2x3½'.